# How to connect and performe aggregation queries using mongoDb and kotlin

Tags: android, mongodb, kotlin, aggregation-framework

I have managed to connect a kotlin project made in jetpack compose to mongodatabase and can performe CRUD operations.

I am trying to learn how to performe a simple aggregation query such as matching the users age with 20. Lets say that there are 100 people in the document and 35 people with the age of 20. I want the following message "You matched with: 35 people" to be displayed when I press a buttom and this number will adapt dependent on what age the user chooses. Meaning age of 40 will match with 20 users etc that are age 40 within a set of 100 people.

How can this be done using mongoDb and kotlin language in jetpack compose? Appreciate any feedback or advice!

All documents in MongoDb - People (database) - Person (Document with people).

Person documents:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"657215a949d94809dec506a7"},"age":{"$numberLong":"20"},"gender":"Male","name":"michael","owner_id":"655e73a6df44477a94ebcd92","timestamp":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1701975465500"}}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"65721693c4f9cf773c6b3012"},"age":{"$numberLong":"25"},"gender":"Female","name":"emma","owner_id":"655e73a6df44477a94ebcd92","timestamp":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1701975699821"}}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"6572174a9b39c805055c78e3"},"age":{"$numberLong":"25"},"gender":"Female","name":"emily","owner_id":"655e73a6df44477a94ebcd92","timestamp":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1701975882620"}}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"65721a09f8210042ebfb4b40"},"age":{"$numberLong":"20"},"gender":"Female","name":"maria","owner_id":"655e73a6df44477a94ebcd92","timestamp":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1701976585960"}}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"657370238125ee55f7599270"},"age":{"$numberLong":"26"},"gender":"Female","name":"stina","owner_id":"655e73a6df44477a94ebcd92","timestamp":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1702064163288"}}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"6573731a7c36dc7b557ed5ea"},"age":{"$numberLong":"30"},"gender":"Female","name":"sammantha","owner_id":"655e73a6df44477a94ebcd92","timestamp":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1702064922633"}}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"657608bacbc4a36db6fe91a4"},"age":{"$numberLong":"23"},"gender":"Male","name":"smith","owner_id":"655e73a6df44477a94ebcd92","timestamp":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1702234298072"}}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"65760b652a03d126a0199147"},"age":{"$numberLong":"28"},"gender":"Male","name":"tony","owner_id":"655e73a6df44477a94ebcd92","timestamp":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1702234981496"}}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"657ca41582c09d0eeee7effa"},"age":{"$numberLong":"51"},"gender":"Male","name":"samma","owner_id":"655e73a6df44477a94ebcd92","timestamp":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1702667285298"}}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"657f546c9fbc7019f9d7cd5a"},"age":{"$numberLong":"20"},"gender":"Male","name":"sixten","owner_id":"655e73a6df44477a94ebcd92","timestamp":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1702843500413"}}}
```

Main database:

```
class Person : RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.invoke()
    var owner_id: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    var age: Int? = 18
    var gender: String? = ""

    var timestamp: RealmInstant = RealmInstant.now()
}
```

Main Display of data:

```
@Composable
fun MainMongoData() {
    var fetchedData by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column {
        // Display your fetched data in a TextField
        TextField(
            value = fetchedData,
            onValueChange = { /* No-op for read-only TextField */ },
            label = { Text("Fetched Data") },
            readOnly = true,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )

        // Button to trigger search
        Button(onClick = {
            val client = getMongoClient()
            val database = client.getDatabase("people")
            val collection = database.getCollection("person")

            val documents = fetchDataFromMongoDB(collection)

            // Concatenate document JSON strings and update the TextField
            fetchedData = documents.joinToString("\n") { it.toJson() }

            client.close()
        }) {
            Text("Search")
        }
    }
}
```

GetMongoClient:

```
@SuppressLint("AuthLeak")
fun getMongoClient(): MongoClient {
    return MongoClients.create("My String goes here -> taken from mongodb")
}
```

FetchDataFromMongoDb:

```
fun fetchDataFromMongoDB(collection: MongoCollection<Document>): List<Document> {
    // Define your aggregation pipeline stages here
    val pipeline = listOf(
        Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("age", "20")),
        // Add more pipeline stages as needed
    )

    // Execute the aggregation pipeline
    val result = collection.aggregate(pipeline)


    // Convert the result to a list of documents
    val documents = mutableListOf<Document>()

    try {
        // Code that might be causing the exception
        result.forEach { document ->
            documents.add(document)
            println("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!")

        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }


    return documents
}
```

Dependencies:

```
// Mongo Realm
implementation ("io.realm.kotlin:library-sync:1.13.0") // <-- this is the main implementations that works with the app.
implementation("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.11.0")

// MongoDB Kotlin driver dependency
implementation("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-kotlin-coroutine:4.11.0")
```

ERROR when buttom "Search" is pressed:

```
2024-01-23 22:47:49.506  1134-2162  OneSearchS...stProvider com...le.android.apps.nexuslauncher  E  Failed to fetch suggestions from AppSearch, fallback to AGA
                                                                                                    java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:323)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniAccept.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:684)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:486)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2138)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher.allapps.H0.onResult(Unknown Source:59)
                                                                                                        at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1.lambda$onResult$0(SearchSessionUtil.java:129)
                                                                                                        at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1.$r8$lambda$_nlk9WiPjSfaAsqKYmp0aPvSRC0(SearchSessionUtil.java:1)
                                                                                                        at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(R8$$SyntheticClass:13)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
                                                                                                        at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:144)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher.allapps.H0.onResult(Unknown Source:16)
                                                                                                        at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1.lambda$onResult$0(SearchSessionUtil.java:129) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1.$r8$lambda$_nlk9WiPjSfaAsqKYmp0aPvSRC0(SearchSessionUtil.java:1) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(R8$$SyntheticClass:13) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Comment: please provide example of your data. You're speaking about ***the*** document (single document with multiple embedded documents/payloads), but expect to have multiple different documents with single (?) payload

Comment: Hello! Yes, will provide the database called "people" that is located in a "person" document. This person document contains multiple types of people. Each has their properties such as name, age, gender etc. Will implement that in the code as well! @dododo

Comment: do not post links. Use plain text instead

Comment: alright will convert it into text

Comment: will add more "person" / data to the document when the main issue with connecting and performing aggregation is solved.

Comment: then what exactly doesn't work here: `val result = collection.aggregate(pipeline)`. What do you see in the result?

Comment: the following error above happens when the buttom "searched" is pressed. Also, no information is being displayed in the selected textfield as seen above. @dododo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256664/discussion-between-dododo-and-josef-m).

Comment: Anyone else has an idea of how to solve this issue?